# Script to add user and assign to group in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

A bit new to linux and I have a task with the following requirements (I'd like to create a script to automate this):

1. create a linux user (NO SUDO)
2. create password for each (write passwd to file for each creation)
3. set proper BIN path to aws cli
4. add all users to "users" group

This is what I have so far, but I am stumped on steps 3 & 4. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
//execute the Script using a bash shell
#!/bin/bash

//location of the txt file of usernames
userfile=/tmp/userlist 

//extracting usernames from the file one-by-one
username=$(cat /tmp/userlist | tr 'A-Z'  'a-z')

//defining the default password 
password=$username@123

//running loop  to add users
for user in $username
do
       //adding users '$user' is a variable that changes
       // usernames accordingly in txt file.
       useradd $user
       echo $password | passwd --stdin $user
done
```

Comment: What do you  mean in step 3? Add user's /.local/bin to a AWS's PATH variable?

Comment: @SantiagoEchevarria I plan on going into each of those users and performing aws configure command to add user key and secret.

Comment: Step 3 is probably achieved the easiest way by placing a preconfigured `.bashrc` in the home directories of your new users. Step 4 should be trivial with minimal research effort.